# Font-face with Internet Explorer

Tags: font-face

Does anyone know are there any issues with using more than 1 or 2 @font-face declarations with IE? I'm only getting one typeface to display, the other won't at all.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you generated the right fonts to work with Internet Explorer (eot)?  This tutorial: [Generating custom fonts with @font-face](http://www.webistrate.com/css3-custom-fonts-using-font-face/) describes generating the correct syntax to support all browsers.  No reason why multiple wouldn't work.  If you're still having some issues perhaps you can post your code or example link?

Comment: Thanks endyourif, I didn't actually have the right block created. Re-generating it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't be. I have three of them working here: [@font-face :: IM FELL English](http://www.iandevlin.com/font-face/).

Comment: Don't you just love those who downvote without a reason. So brave.